# Why does this while loop execute but produce the incorrect answer?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

> Cobalt-60, a radioactive form of cobalt used in cancer therapy,
>   decays over a period of time. Each year, 12% of the amount present at the beginning of the year will have decayed. If a container of cobalt-60 initially contains 10 grams, determine the amount remaining after five years.

The code that I have used is:

```
year = 0
cobalt_life = 10
while cobalt_life == 10:
      cobalt_life -= 0.12*cobalt_life
      year +=5
print(cobalt_life)
```

The output is 8.8 when I run this. It should be 5.28. What am I missing?

Comment: This will only run once because as soon as you decrement `cobalt_life` it's no longer10

Comment: In the very first iteration, `cobalt_life` becomes 8.8. In the next iteration, `while` loop checks if it is still 10, but since it is 8.8, breaks, and moves on to print.

Comment: Because `while cobalt_life == 10:` can't possibly be True after you reduce it in the loop even a single time

Comment: if i change it to < 10 i still do not get the answer as 5.28

Comment: It starts at `10`, so you never even enter the loop because `10` is not less than `10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for` loop instead:

```
n_years = 5
cobalt_life = 10
for _ in range(n_years):
    cobalt_life *= 0.88
print(cobalt_life)
# 5.277319168
```

**Editted**

If you want to use `while` loop:

```
n_years = 5
cobalt_life = 10
while n_years:
    cobalt_life *= 0.88
    n_years -= 1
print(cobalt_life)
# 5.277319168
```

Comment: I know how to execute with for loop but I am trying with while loop because i am weak in it

Comment: @joT Added `while` loop version as well

Answer (score 0):

On the second pass of the while loop, cobalt_life is no longer 10 (since on the first pass it changed it)
You want to make the condition of your loop the year, and only increment it by 1 on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after your first iteration, `cobalt_life` is no longer equal to `10`. The condition being `False`, the loop terminates. If you want a loop, you should increment your `year` until it reaches `5`.

Although, note that the calculation you are attempting to do does not require a loop at all, but should instead be achieved using exponentiation.

```
n_years = 5
cobalt_life = 10 * 0.88 ** 5 #  5.277319168
```